# OSError: invalid pixel size - Decrease size of NotoColorEmoji Font in python

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library, emoji

i am using Pillow to draw text on image
I HAVE  emoji in the text and using NotoColorEmoji showing colored emoji my code is

```
def process_meme_video_bottom_layer(video1, caption, solid_color, font, text_color, plain_text, emojis_text):
    """
    process meme video bottom layer
    """
    #create an image object
    img = Image.new('RGB', video1.size, color=solid_color)
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    y_pos = int(1920 * 0.04)
    # Split caption into text and emojis
    emojis_list = [c for c in caption if emoji.is_emoji(c)]
    emojis_text = ''.join(emojis_list)
    plain_text = ''.join([c for c in caption if c not in emojis_list])
    plain_text = textwrap.wrap(plain_text, width=25)
    # Draw plain text
    for txt in plain_text:
        y_pos += int(1920 * 0.04)
        logger.info('txt %s', txt)
        text_width, text_height = d.textsize(txt, font=font)
        text_x_position = int((1080 - text_width) / 2)
        text_y_pos = y_pos
        text_position = (text_x_position, text_y_pos)
        d.text(text_position, txt, fill=text_color, font=font)
        logger.info('text x position %s', text_x_position)
        logger.info('text width %s', str(text_width))
    # Set the x-coordinate for emojis to be immediately after the last drawn text
    emoji_x_position = text_x_position + text_width
    emoji_y_position = y_pos
    # Draw emojis with color
    emoji_font = ImageFont.truetype("NotoColorEmoji.ttf", 109)
    emoji_position = (emoji_x_position, emoji_y_position)
    d.text(emoji_position, emojis_text, font=emoji_font, fill=text_color, embedded_color=True)
    img.show()
    img_array = np.array(img)
    bottom_layer = ImageClip(img_array, ismask=False).set_duration(video1.duration)
    return bottom_layer
```

now  when I use 80, or something else instead of 109
OSerror invalid pixel error

Is there any way we can decrase the size of emojo or anyother approach to showing colored emoji in image.